# Proving by residue class.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How it can be proved that $x^{2}−y^{2}=34$ has no integer value solution in the set Z.

I have come across a solution that takes for a given modulus, the residue class of any integer, then the square, then finally the difference of squares. It attempts to show for a particular value, say 4 that the modulus residue classes are different for 34 and any difference of squares of integers. Say, the below solution attempts this strategy for modulus as 4.

For 4 the possible residue are: {0, 1, 2, 3}.

The squares have the possible residue : {0, 1}.

The differences of squares can have possible residues : {0, 1, 3}.

The residue of 34 modulo 4 is 2.

Hence, proved.

I want to know that if this method fails for another modulus value; then will it not be enough to prove otherwise. Say, for modulus = 5, the residues are : { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}. The squares have the possible residues : {0, 1, 4}. The differences of squares have the residue values in the set :{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, derived as below:

$0-0 =0; 0-1 =4; 1-0 =1; 4-1 =3; 1-4 =2; 4-0 =4; 0-4 =1$

Now, 34 mod 5 has residue 4. So, the logic of proving the question should fail by this strategy.

Comment: Choice of modulus is the key here :  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893394/solving-x2-11y2-3-using-congruences,  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987396/prove-that-x2-y2-3z2-m2-has-no-solutions-in-integer

Comment: So, you mean that failure is the key. Once failed, it is not possible, even if proved possible by this method for another modulus value. Can you give logical reason, if I am correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the equation can be solved in integers, it can be solved in any modulus - because you can just take an integer solution and regard it as a solution in that modulus.

So if there is any modulus for which the equation has no solution it can't have a solution in integers. So finding a modulus for which the equation fails is a useful technique for proving there is no solution, since it requires only a finite amount of work.

---

It is a much more subtle question whether, if there is a solution to every modulus, there is a solution in integers - this depends on whether the solutions are compatible with each other.

Here results like the Chinese Remainder Theorem can provide help to stitch together a finite number of solutions.

---

With squares it is often useful to notice that even squares are divisible by $4$ and odd squares can be written as $$(2n+1)^2 =8\cdot \frac {n(n+1)} 2+1$$ and therefore always give remainder $1$ when divided by $8$.

---

For the question $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$ is the product of two numbers of the same parity (the factors differ by the even number $2y$), so is either odd or divisible by $4$.

Comment: I am a novice in the residue classes arithmetic & would like to request source for your assertion that : So finding a modulus for which the equation fails is a useful technique for proving there is no solution, since it requires only a finite amount of work.

Comment: @jiten If there is such a modulus (for which the equation fails), then there are only finitely many residue classes to check. And if there is such a modulus, it is itself finite. You can't necessarily bound the time to search for the modulus, but the search terminates. Of course if there is a solution, the search may not terminate, but the search will give an intelligent searcher clues abut what the solution may look like. Often in practice, and with some experience (as here) careful choice of modulus gives a quick answer.

Comment: Please give some source, as it will aid a lot in further understanding and delving further.

Comment: @jiten I don't have a source, it is simply an observation, which I hoped I had justified. You only need one counterexample.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your observation. But, anything like this must be too obvious via something axiomatic, that you are missing. May be, something is so basic that defines everything you have said. Please elaborate, if possible the axiomatic definition that defines your earlier stated assertion.

Comment: @jiten There are only finitely many distinct residues to any finite modulus ...

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2-y^2=34$$

$x$ and $y$ are odd or $x$ and $y$ are even simultaneously.

Then
$4|x^2-y^2$. But $4\not|34$

Comment: I feel either I have not understood your comment, or my below comment is valid:     Not necessary that both are odd or even simultaneously. It is possible that one is odd and other is even. Say x = 3, y =2; hence $x^{2} = 9$, and $y^{2} = 4$. Also, now $x^{2} - y^{2}$ = 5; which is not divisible by 4.